# addSubview: re-writes the navigation stack?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on a app which uses the controller containment pattern as described in the View Controller documentation in the iOS SDK.

I've written the controller container, and it works great. My controller is basically containing two sub views and it displays them both at the same time, sliding one over the other depending on what the user is doing. Works wonderful.

Now, I want to use this container controller in a navigation view. This is to get push segues to work. In effect, from my contained controllers, I want to be able to use the navigation stack, push a new controller on, and pop when the user is done.

However, I have noticed that if the navigation view is instantiated with my container controller as the root container, things fall apart.

In particular, I have noticed this:

In the iOS documentation, container controllers call addChildController: and then addSubview:.  This seems to break the navigation stack, as the push segue does not work - it behaves like modal. I believe it does this because addSubview resets the navigation stack.

I confirmed this by replacing addChildController and addSubview with [self.navigationController pushViewController...]. I confirmed it is a problem with addSubview because I can reproduce the issue when I omit the call to addChildController.

When I do this, the navigation stack works properly. But of course, my container controller does not, as only the "most recently pushed" controller is visible.

I'm doing this because in my contained controllers, I want to push a new controller onto the stack, and when the user is done, I want to "pop" the stack, without reloading the "previous controller".

Using a modal segue reloads the previous controller; using a push controller does not.

I cannot find any documentation on the behavior of addSubview and it's effect on the navigation stack.

Thank you in advance for any light you guys can shed!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of trouble completely understanding what you are doing, but I think that what you want to do is exactly what I'm doing.

I have a UINavigationController that has as its rootView a container UIViewController. That controller adds children per the normal methods. One of those children views pushes other views that may get popped.

One of those pushed views COULD message the appDelegate and make itself the rootViewController if it wanted to. In general, as long as you keep a strong reference to a view controller, you can remove it from whoever 'owns' it, and muck around with the navigationControllers viewControllers array to your hearts content.